# Julia: How to obtain the Array pointed at by pointer?

Tags: pointers, julia

```
a = [1,2,3]
ap = pointer(ap)
```

Suppose, I am only given `ap`, how do I get back a `Vector{Int}` that the pointer `AP` was pointing at without using `unsafe_load`?

Comment: Just wondering, why are you working with pointers in the first place? I am having trouble thinking of a place where this is a good idea in Julia

Comment: I have a large dataframe containing 100 column. Each column is stored compressed. So I load the compressed data into RAM, but keep a pointer to an uncompressed arrray. Upon acces, the compress array is decompressed. So my memory structure is compressed array and pointer to decompresssed. Saves memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unsafe_warp` function to wrap back a pointer to a Julia array. See [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.unsafe_wrap-Union%7BTuple%7BN%7D,%20Tuple%7BT%7D,%20Tuple%7BUnion%7BType%7BArray%7D,%20Type%7BArray%7BT,N%7D%20where%20N%7D,%20Type%7BArray%7BT,N%7D%7D%7D,Ptr%7BT%7D,Tuple%7BVararg%7BInt64,N%7D%7D%7D%7D%20where%20N%20where%20T)

By the way, `pointer` doesn't work anymore, you can use `Base.unsafe_convert` instead. Here is an example of using both

```
a = [1,2,3]
ap = Base.unsafe_convert(Ptr{Clonglong}, a)
a2 = unsafe_wrap(Vector{Int64}, ap, 3, own=false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use pointers in Julia to reference an object. To reference an object, use a `Ref`, like so: `reference = Ref(obj)`. To dereference: `obj = reference[]`. A `Ref` is lightweight, plays nice with the garbage collector and doesn't lead to segfaults.

Pointers can be useful in Julia, but generally only to do weird read/write operations. If you only have a pointer (for some reason), you can create an `Array` pointing to that memory using `unsafe_wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is not to use `pointer` as that's designed for C. YOu should use

`pointer_from_objref`. E.g.

```
x = [1,2,3]
x === unsafe_pointer_to_objref(pointer_from_objref(x))
```